# In R, get the text and corresponding filename of every file in a ZIP archive

Tags: r

I have a bunch of ZIP archives that each contain a bunch of text files. I want to read all the text into memory, one string per file, and with each file tagged with the corresponding filename, but without removing the original ZIP files or writing all the contents to disk. (If writing temporary files is a must, they should be deleted once we're done reading them, or if processing is interrupted.)

For example, suppose you create a simple ZIP like this:

```
$ echo 'contents1' > file1
$ echo 'contents2' > file2
$ zip files.zip file1 file2
```

Then calling `myfunction("files.zip")` should return the same thing as `list(file1 = "contents1\n", file2 = "contents2\n")`.

I currently use the following function, which uses Info-ZIP `unzip`. It works fine, except that its code to detect the end of one file and the beginning of another might trigger on file contents instead.

```
library(stringr)

slurp.zip = function(path)
  # Extracts each file in the zip file at `path` as a single
  # string. The names of the resulting list are set to the inner
  # file names.
   {lines = system2("unzip", c("-c", path), stdout = T)
    is.sep = str_detect(lines, "^ (?: inflating|extracting): ")
    chunks = lapply(
        split(lines[!is.sep], cumsum(is.sep)[!is.sep])[-1],
        function(chunk) paste(chunk, collapse = "\n"))
    fnames = str_match(lines[is.sep], "^ (?: inflating|extracting): (.+)  $")
    stopifnot(!anyNA(fnames))
    names(chunks) = fnames[,2]
    chunks}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of input and the output desired?

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade Done.

Comment: Are you working under windows or unix?

Comment: @PoGibas Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unzip(..., list = TRUE)` to get the file names in the archive, without actually extracting them.  Then we can use `unz` to create connections to the files, which can be read using e.g. `readLines` or `scan`:

```
slurp.zip = function(path) {
  sapply(unzip(path, list = TRUE)$Name, function(x) 
    paste0(readLines(unz('files.zip', x)), collapse = '\n'), 
    simplify =  FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
}

dput(slurp.zip('files.zip'))
# list(file1 = "contents1\n", file2 = "contents2\n")
```

Comment: Doesn't this decompress the same file repeatedly, once for each contained file?

Comment: Never mind; I remembered that ZIP compresses its member files individually rather than all together as a single unit. So this looks fine to me.